# How to Create Computed Values in @default Directives

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Using [`Prisma's SDL`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.2/reference/service-configuration/data-modelling-(sdl)-eiroozae8u/) I’d like to create a computed value with the `@default` directive like this…

```
type Event {
  id: ID! @unique

  title: String!
  slug: String! @unique @default(value: titleToSlug())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic default values are currently not supported, and can be handled in the application server layer. You can create a feature request for dynamic default values [here](https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/issues/new?template=feature_request.md).

The directive is called `@default` and not `@defaultValue` as described [in the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.2/reference/service-configuration/data-modelling-(sdl)-eiroozae8u/#default-value).

Comment: Thanks for confirming Nilan. [I've submitted this as a feature request](https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/issues/2747). I've also changed all instances of `@defaultValue` to `@default` in my original post so it doesn't confuse anyone.